# using poly( function within training model in caret package resulting in dataframe error

Tags: r, r-caret

Here's the code that I am running:

```
library(caret)
library(ISLR)
data('Auto')
cverror <- c()
for(i in 1:5){
  train_control <- trainControl(method='LOOCV')
  models <- train(mpg~poly(horsepower,i), data = Auto, trControl=train_control, method='glm')
  cverror[i] <- (models$results$RMSE)^2
}

cverror
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to calculate the MSE (mean square error) for different polynomial levels using a loop so I don't have to code line by line. The error message I receive is:

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Why am I receiving this error? My study mates said that this code runs fine on their machine, but it doesn't work on my personal or work computers. I have the latest RStudio and R versions installed with all packages up to date.

The following line of code works just fine:

```
train(mpg~poly(horsepower,2), data = Auto, trControl=train_control, method='glm')
```

This is in relation to the tutorial found on page 192/193 of the ISLR text (which I'm expanding upon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `i <- 2` its value is not substituted into the formula. The formula is literally `mpg ~ poly(horsepower, i)`.

Try this:

```
library(caret)
library(ISLR)
data('Auto')
cverror <- numeric(5)
for(i in 1:5){
  train_control <- trainControl(method='LOOCV')
  f <- bquote(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, .(i)))
  models <- train(as.formula(f), data = Auto, trControl=train_control, method='glm')
  cverror[i] <- (models$results$RMSE)^2
}

cverror
#[1] 24.23151 19.24821 19.33498 19.42443 19.03321
```

PS: Higher degree polynomials pretty much guarantee over-fitting. I'd not recommend a polynomial of a degree higher than 2, maybe 3. There are usually better models available in such a case. Higher degree polynomials are rare for "natural" processes.

Comment: Can you help me understand what the function, "bquote" does? I've never used (nor heard of) this function before. The help document (?bquote) was not very helpful.

Comment: It creates an expression, but takes the variable given in `.()` from the enclosing environment and substitutes its value into the expression.

Comment: If you prefer you could use `sprintf` or even `paste` instead.

Comment: Roland, what's very odd is that Nik's original code works perfectly on my machine, without having to use `bquote` or `as.formula`. I know we have different versions of R and RStudio; perhaps the function's behaviour changes over the version change?

Comment: @Rahul I'm not aware of changes in R that would impact this.

Comment: @NikhilAgarwal I tried your code on my windows machine at work, and get the exact error you are facing. R ver 3.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Have you tried using the following?

```
models <- train(x = poly(Auto$horsepower,i), y = Auto$mpg, data = Auto, trControl=train_control, method='glm')
```

(I have not tested this specific piece of code.)

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer, please avoid answering old questions if it dosent add anything new to the existing answers.